# In PHP While using exec() or system() function the default user had been taking

Tags: php

By default when system() and exec() functions are used in PHP the default user is SYSTEM so I can never see the result. Is there a way to change the user it runs it as administrator

Sumit

Comment: See the result? Maybe you should describe, post code of how are you trying to do that first. Also add platform info.

Comment: i have a xampp server and i m writing a code in a notpad++

Answer (score 1):

Calling anything from PHP as a root is danger. Try to allow access to specific resource for the default user instead.

Comment: Totally agree with hsz.

Comment: How to specify a default user

Comment: I had build a exe file from Visual Fox Pro 9 and i want to call its from php programm is it possible